# Решить задание , оформив каждую команду в виде отдельной функции

Tags: python

**Решил задачу без примирения функции, условия таковы:**
Использовать словарь, содержащий следующие ключи: название товара; название магазина, в котором продается товар; стоимость товара в руб. Написать программу, выполняющую следующие действия: ввод с клавиатуры данных в список, состоящий из словарей заданной структуры; записи должны быть размещены в алфавитном порядке по названиям товаров; вывод на экран информации о товаре, название которого введено с клавиатуры; если таких товаров нет, выдать на дисплей соответствующее сообщение.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
# Список .
products = []

# Организовать бесконечный цикл запроса команд.
while True:
    # Запросить команду из терминала.
    command = input(">>> ").lower()

    # Выполнить действие в соответствие с командой.
    if command == 'exit':
        break

    elif command == 'add':
        # Запросить данные .
        name = input("Название продукта ")
        nameShop = input("Название магазина ")
        cost = input("Стоимость товара (руб.) ")

        # Создать словарь.
        product = {
            'name': name,
            'nameShop': nameShop,
            'cost': cost,
        }

        # Добавить словарь в список.
        products.append(product)
        # Отсортировать список в случае необходимости.
        if len(products) > 1:
            product.sort(key=lambda item: item.get('name', ''))

    elif command == 'list':
        # Заголовок таблицы.
        line = '+-{}-+-{}-+-{}-+-{}-+'.format(
            '-' * 4,
            '-' * 30,
            '-' * 20,
            '-' * 8
        )
        print(line)
        print(
            '| {:^4} | {:^30} | {:^20} | {:^8} |'.format(
                "No",
                "Название товара",
                "Название магазина",
                "Цена",
            )
        )
        print(line)

        # Вывести данные о всех товарах.
        for idx, product in enumerate(products, 1):
            print(
                '| {:>4} | {:<30} | {:<20} | {:>8} |'.format(
                    idx,
                    product.get('name', ''),
                    product.get('nameShop', ''),
                    product.get('cost', 0)
                )
            )

        print(line)

    elif command.startswith('select '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=2)
        sel = (parts[1])

        count = 0
        for products in products:
            if products.get('name') == sel:
                count = "Цена"
                print(
                    '{:>4}: {}'.format(count, products.get('cost', ''))
                )
                print('Название магазина:', products.get('nameShop', ''))
                print('Название товара:', products.get('name', ''))

        # Если счетчик равен 0, то товар не найдены.
        if count == 0:
            print("Товар не найден.")

    elif command == 'help':
        # Вывести справку о работе с программой.
        print("Список команд:\n")
        print("add - добавить товар;")
        print("list - вывести список рейсов;")
        print("select <товар> - информация о товаре;")
        print("help - отобразить справку;")
        print("exit - завершить работу с программой.")

    else:
        print("Неизвестная команда {command}", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: ок, но в вашем вопросе нет вопроса...

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм:

1. Прочитать в учебнике главу про функции, чтобы понять что это и как работает.
2. Вынести отдельные блоки кода в функции.
3. На их место поставить вызов соответствующих функций.
4. Исправить возможные ошибки.
5. Профит!